# How can I use the props from another file in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have two files: EnhancedTableHEad and OrderDialog. I need the props data from EnhancedTabledHead in my OrderDialog file. How can I achieve that ? My files look like this:

```css
//OrderDialog.jsx

import EnhancedTableHead from '../../Table/EnhancedTableHead';

render() {
        const {classes, data, onClose, onClick, item, isSelected, rowCount, onSelectAllClick, ...other} = this.props;
        return ()
        }
```

```html
//EnhancedTableHead.jsx

 render() {
        const {onSelectAllClick, order, orderBy, numSelected, rowCount, tableConfiguration} = this.props;
        return ()
        }


EnhancedTableHead.propTypes = {
    numSelected: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    onRequestSort: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    order: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    orderBy: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    rowCount: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    onChange: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
};

export default EnhancedTableHead;
```

Am I understaing this wrong ? For example, I want to use rowCount from EnhancedTableHead in my OrderDialog, but when I do console.log I get undefined. If I do it inside the EnahancedTableHead, console.log will print the right value.

Comment: Are these two components used by the same 'parent' component?

Comment: take a look at react context

Comment: I see that you already got a reply :)

Answer (score 0):

Spread them in OrderDialog. ie

```
OrderDialog.propTypes = {
 ...EnhancedTableHead.propTypes
}
```

Comment: If I do this I get: function checkType() {
    [native code]
}